# how to append the cookies values

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have four cookie values like $.cookie('line1side1',{ path:'/'}) and $.cookie('line2side1',{ path:'/'})

I want to append this all values and assign it to the one text-box.

document.getElementsByName('Custom_Field_Custom7')[0].value= all values of cookie

How should I write?

Answer (score 0):

This uses jQuery (I'm assuming you're using it since you reference $.cookie). Basically you can grab the current cookie collection, split it into the cookies and map the values into an array. Then just join the array and dump it into your textbox.

```
alert($.map(document.cookie.split(";"), function(c){ return c.split("=")[0];  }).join(", "));
```